# Android SIGSEGV when drawing Path using Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, opengl-es, segmentation-fault

We are experiencing a SIGSEGV when attempting to draw a Path using HW acceleration. It happens after my draw() call so I believe it happens when the OpenGL layer tries to render the display list. There is nothing remarkable about the Path and it doesn't happen all the time. Device is Nexus 4, Note 2, or Nexus 10 running 4.2.2.

```
05-08 18:42:58.577: A/libc(2905): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000005 (code=1), thread 2905 (...)
05-08 18:42:58.682: I/DEBUG(118): Build fingerprint: 'google/mantaray/manta:4.4/KRT16O/907817:user/release-keys'
05-08 18:42:58.682: I/DEBUG(118): Revision: '8'
05-08 18:42:58.682: I/DEBUG(118): pid: 2905, tid: 2905, name: ...  >>> ... <<<
05-08 18:42:58.682: I/DEBUG(118): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000005
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     r0 00000001  r1 bef854ac  r2 783fa714  r3 75d163e0
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     r4 752ceac0  r5 bef854ac  r6 c8a804c0  r7 75e53128
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     r8 bef85508  r9 41dfca70  sl 420b73d8  fp bef8551c
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     ip 40c36b20  sp bef854a0  lr 40c26bd1  pc 4019e51c  cpsr a0030030
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000020
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d2  0000000000000010  d3  0000000000000030
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  3f7fe0003f800000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d8  3f8000003f800000  d9  408698cad3d39818
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d10 4380000000000100  d11 44b1800044d10000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d12 44d1800044f10000  d13 414b05d200000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d14 3fecd0c2f5b24766  d15 0000000000000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d16 0000000000000008  d17 0000000000000001
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 000000763b3ca000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 0000000000000001
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d22 0000000000000025  d23 0000000000000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d24 00000000761b6140  d25 00000000761b6141
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 3fc86c6e00000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d28 bfef697d60000000  d29 4054539880000000
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     d30 0000000000000001  d31 0000000000000001
05-08 18:42:58.737: I/DEBUG(118):     scr 20000013
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118): backtrace:
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #00  pc 0000b51c  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::incStrong(void const*) const+1)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #01  pc 00024bcd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #02  pc 00024e29  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #03  pc 00024e59  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #04  pc 0001cd7d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #05  pc 00065c4b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #06  pc 0001db4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #07  pc 0004e083  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #08  pc 00026f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #09  pc 0002df78  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #10  pc 0002b5dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #11  pc 00060789  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #12  pc 000686f7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #13  pc 00026f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #14  pc 0002df78  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #15  pc 0002b5dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #16  pc 000604a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #17  pc 00049c6b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #18  pc 0004cd7f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #19  pc 0004daa3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #20  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #21  pc 0000e3e7  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):     #22  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118): stack:
05-08 18:42:58.742: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85460  bef8549c  [stack]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85464  7465c01d  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85468  752cb218  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef8546c  bef854ac  [stack]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85470  0000290a  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85474  752cb220  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85478  bef85508  [stack]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef8547c  4012b2e3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50)
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85480  40164000  /system/lib/libc.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85484  752cb220  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85488  752cb220  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef8548c  bef854ac  [stack]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85490  0000290a  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85494  40127ca9  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef85498  40c364c8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef8549c  40c26a73  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):     #00  bef854a0  752ceac0  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854a4  40c26bd1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):     #01  bef854a8  75e53128  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854ac  00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854b0  783fa714  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854b4  75e5312c  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854b8  783fa6e4  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854bc  00000004  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854c0  41dfca78  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854c4  40c26e2b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):     #02  bef854c8  75e53128  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854cc  75e5312c  [anon:libc_malloc]
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854d0  00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.747: I/DEBUG(118):          bef854d4  40c26e5d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118): memory near r1:
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8548c bef854ac 0000290a 40127ca9 40c364c8  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8549c 40c26a73 752ceac0 40c26bd1 75e53128  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854ac 00000001 783fa714 75e5312c 783fa6e4  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854bc 00000004 41dfca78 40c26e2b 75e53128  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854cc 75e5312c 00000000 40c26e5d 40c362f0  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854dc 75fbbe18 420b73c8 40c1ed81 6d7d63f8  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854ec 420b73c8 00000000 41dfca78 bef85508  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854fc 40244c4d 41dfcaa4 4155eb50 41dfca70  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8550c 00000001 00000008 420e4f60 426ac2a8  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8551c 4158f087 41dfca70 6f1de47e 40244c43  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8552c 420b73d8 75e5def0 6ed9f0ee 11900019  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8553c 00000000 6f4fa000 40168384 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8554c bef85638 00000000 bef8568c f0000000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8555c 41a2a3d6 ff000000 41bfffff 00000040  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8556c 42800000 44b6e000 c5053000 44bee000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8557c c5013000 00000000 00000026 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118): memory near r2:
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa6f4 40800000 40c00000 00000000 75e66bc0  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa704 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa714 752ceac0 00000000 783fa664 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.752: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa724 0000001b 0000000a 00000001 4c2d6e65  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa734 2d6e7461 00005355 0000005b 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa744 41e00000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa754 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa764 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa774 fff3f3f3 00000000 40800000 0b000501  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa784 783fa798 00000001 00000001 00000009  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa794 0000001b 0000000a 00000002 4c2d6e65  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa7a4 2d6e7461 00005355 0000005b 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa7b4 41400000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa7c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa7d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     783fa7e4 ff000000 00000000 40800000 0b000501  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118): memory near r3:
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d163c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 75d166e4  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d163d0 754ebc04 754e6514 00000000 000000cb  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d163e0 754e2480 75d1675c 75d16034 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d163f0 00000002 000001cf 00000001 75d164b4  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16400 75d164b4 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16410 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16420 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16430 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16440 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16450 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16460 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16470 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16480 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d16490 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d164a0 00000000 00000023 00000002 000001cf  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     75d164b0 00000006 00000000 00000000 75d163e0  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118): memory near r4:
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceaa0 00000001 00000001 80808080 00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceab0 00000001 00000001 00000001 0000005b  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceac0 754cc898 75fee830 00000000 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752cead0 0000011a 75d163e0 00000001 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceae0 00000000 00000000 0000812f 0000812f  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceaf0 00000002 00002601 27547000 00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb00 029d7000 00000000 27547802 00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb10 00000058 0000001b 6d7df670 00000018  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb20 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000053  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb30 402863c0 00000003 4062c1a8 42417438  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb40 00000000 075bcd15 00000003 406091bc  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb50 00000101 42417438 00000010 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb60 00000000 00000000 420b5ed0 ffffff01  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb70 1d20049a 00000001 00000002 00000053  
05-08 18:42:58.757: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb80 06020201 752ceba0 752ceba8 00000007  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     752ceb90 00000000 0000000d 00000017 752cebb0  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118): memory near r5:
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8548c bef854ac 0000290a 40127ca9 40c364c8  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8549c 40c26a73 752ceac0 40c26bd1 75e53128  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854ac 00000001 783fa714 75e5312c 783fa6e4  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854bc 00000004 41dfca78 40c26e2b 75e53128  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854cc 75e5312c 00000000 40c26e5d 40c362f0  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854dc 75fbbe18 420b73c8 40c1ed81 6d7d63f8  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854ec 420b73c8 00000000 41dfca78 bef85508  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854fc 40244c4d 41dfcaa4 4155eb50 41dfca70  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8550c 00000001 00000008 420e4f60 426ac2a8  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8551c 4158f087 41dfca70 6f1de47e 40244c43  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8552c 420b73d8 75e5def0 6ed9f0ee 11900019  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8553c 00000000 6f4fa000 40168384 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8554c bef85638 00000000 bef8568c f0000000  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8555c 41a2a3d6 ff000000 41bfffff 00000040  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8556c 42800000 44b6e000 c5053000 44bee000  
05-08 18:42:58.762: I/DEBUG(118):     bef8557c c5013000 00000000 00000026 00000000  
...snip...
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118): memory near sp:
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85480 40164000 752cb220 752cb220 bef854ac  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85490 0000290a 40127ca9 40c364c8 40c26a73  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854a0 752ceac0 40c26bd1 75e53128 00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854b0 783fa714 75e5312c 783fa6e4 00000004  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854c0 41dfca78 40c26e2b 75e53128 75e5312c  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854d0 00000000 40c26e5d 40c362f0 75fbbe18  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854e0 420b73c8 40c1ed81 6d7d63f8 420b73c8  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef854f0 00000000 41dfca78 bef85508 40244c4d  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85500 41dfcaa4 4155eb50 41dfca70 00000001  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85510 00000008 420e4f60 426ac2a8 4158f087  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85520 41dfca70 6f1de47e 40244c43 420b73d8  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85530 75e5def0 6ed9f0ee 11900019 00000000  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85540 6f4fa000 40168384 00000000 bef85638  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85550 00000000 bef8568c f0000000 41a2a3d6  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85560 ff000000 41bfffff 00000040 42800000  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     bef85570 44b6e000 c5053000 44bee000 c5013000  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118): code around pc:
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e4fc 46206060 bf00bd10 000074d2 4604b510  
05-08 18:42:58.772: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e50c ffe2f7ff f7fd4620 4620ee90 b510bd10  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e51c 1d206844 ef30f7fd f7fd4620 f1b0ef2e  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e52c d1085f80 f04f4621 f7fd4070 68a0ef2c  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e53c 68996803 bd104788 6844b510 f7fd1d20  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e54c 4620ef1c ef18f7fd f1b0b138 d1085f80  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e55c 4070f04f f7fd4621 68a0ef16 68996803  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e56c bd104788 68186843 30044770 beb0f003  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e57c 4604b538 460d3004 ef0af7fd d1192801  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e58c 07d968e3 6823d409 5f80f1b3 e00cd100  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e59c e8bd4620 f0034038 68a0bea3 694a6801  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e5ac 47904629 07c268e0 68a0d504 6801b110  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e5bc 4790684a b570bd38 68444605 4620460e  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e5cc eee6f7fd d10b2801 463168a0 68da6803  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e5dc 68e04790 d40307c0 46286829 4798684b  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     4019e5ec 46314620 4070e8bd bfc2f7ff 4604b570  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118): code around lr:
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26bb0 4607b5f7 2900460c 694bd039 690ead02  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26bc0 435e6cc8 0d04f845 4629b110 ec1af7e7  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26bd0 b1289801 ffd8f7ff f7ff4620 e00dfd84  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26be0 428669f8 4912d907 46332006 44794a11  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26bf0 f7e7447a 69f9ed46 61fa1b8a 3028f897  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c00 490db13b 46332003 44794a0c f7e7447a  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c10 6860ed38 f7eab120 6861fded fea5f7ec  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c20 46206821 4790684a f7ff4628 bdfefef5  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c30 00009c1e 0000afdc 00009c02 0000b00f  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c40 f7ff6811 0000bfb5 4607b5f0 b08b6808  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c50 f844ac0a b1100d18 f7e74621 4829ebd4  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c60 f7ff4478 9b04fc7d a808aa07 9200a909  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c70 9001aa05 68d89102 ab066919 fe32f7ff  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c80 7a05eddd ed9d9804 9e080a06 0a07eddd  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26c90 69439d09 7a10edc3 ed83611e 615d0a11  
05-08 18:42:58.777: I/DEBUG(118):     40c26ca0 0a12edc3 429668fa 4295d81a 2028d818  
05-08 18:42:58.867: I/BootReceiver(450): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
05-08 18:42:58.917: W/ActivityManager(450): Process ... has crashed too many times: killing!
05-08 18:42:58.917: W/ActivityManager(450):   Force finishing activity ...
05-08 18:42:58.967: I/WindowState(450): WIN DEATH: Window{429883a8 u0 ...}
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450): Exception thrown during pause
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:755)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2408)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityStack.java:3475)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2234)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9364)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9284)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:9926)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9478)
05-08 18:42:58.972: W/ActivityManager(450):     at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
05-08 18:42:58.977: I/ActivityManager(450): Killing 2905:.../u0a536 (adj 1): crash
```

Comment: Can you actually post what the problematic API sequence is?

The fact you have reproduced this on 3 devices with three different GPUs, from two different hardware vendors, probably indicates that there is a problem in your API sequence, but it's very hard to help without any information about what you are actually doing.

I'd also note that the backtrace doesn't seem to have much to do with OpenGL ES at all, and the stack looks quite corrupt (libc_malloc won't call into the Mali driver - that doesn't make any sense).

Comment: Oops - just realised how old this one is - sorry ...

Comment: happens to us too, multiple phones